# Regular Expression to Match Full Name with Optional Middle Name

Tags: regex, perl, text

I am writing a Perl program which has a section that loops through a text file and extracts the first and last names of system users. However, on some of the user accounts, they may have a middle name or a middle initial with a period. For example, in the three strings below, I am trying to match John (first name) and Smith (last name) only. I do not want to store the middle name / initial (if there is one):

John Smith

John A. Smith

John Andrew Smith

I have tried to do something like:

```
(\w+)(?:\s.*\w)?\s(\w+).*
```

Where I read and capture the first word (first name) and then have an optional space followed by any characters (middle name) and then a space followed by the last word (last name). But this is not working and I have not been able to come up with any working solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are trying to do something impossible since you can't make the difference between a forename and a part from a lastname in several parts, example: "Boutros Boutros Ghali", "Jean François de la Motte de Chanterac". I suggest to build a form with separated fields.

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing names in any generality is a very rounded and complex problem, and one couldn't really do what is asked for; how do we know how many words are part of the last (or first) name?  However, with names quite like in the example -- where the first and last names are indeed always a single (space-separated) word -- this isn't a problem.

Since you need to split by space and analyze by position, [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) makes it simple. It breaks a string by the given pattern and returns the obtained list. With only the name on the line you can get the first and the last element, which are the first and last name, regardless of the optional middle part. Either

```
my ($first, $last) = (split ' ', $line)[0,-1];
```

or

```
my @name = split ' ', $line;

my $first = shift @name;
my $last  = pop   @name;
```

Or you can use the specific position if there may be trailing items on the line

```
my ($first, $last) = (@name == 2) ? @name : @name[0,2];
```

The pattern used above for space, `' '`, is a little special – it is for any amount of any white space, and it also discards (possible) leading spaces. When general regex patterns for space are used the leading space is kept and we may end up with an empty string for the first element. See [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

If the line is in `$_`, for example with `while (<$fh>)`, you can make use of `split` defaults

```
my ($first, $last) = (split)[0,-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is expecting a word character (`\w`) at the end of the middle name, but your example **John A. Smith** has a dot at the end of the middle name. I would change the pattern like this to accept anything other than space in the middle name, which should solve your issue.

```
(\w+)(?:\s[^\s]+)?\s(\w+).*
```

Comment: I replaced the `w` word character match with `.` to match non-ASCII characters (e.g. unicode) `/(.+)(?:\s[^\s]+)?\s(\w+).*/`

Answer (score -1):

You will almost certainly run into lots of edge cases that do not work. That said, if you are sure your corpus consists only of names in the formats you provided, the following will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @n = (
    "John Smith",
    "John A. Smith",
    "John Andrew Smith",
);
foreach my $full_name (@n) {
    my ($first, $last) = $full_name =~ /^\s*(\S+)\s+(?:\S+\s+)?(\S+)\s*$/;
    print "'$first' '$last'\n";
}
```

You'd be better off capturing the full name and that's all, but loads of legacy systems want, at least, last name on its own. Maybe this will get you closer before manually truing up things.

You can also update the above to remove any number of middle names:

```
my ($first, $last) = $full_name =~ /^\s*(\S+)\s+(?:\S+\s+)*?(\S+)\s*$/;
```

Regarding the answer that is using split... if you do that, update it to split on /\s+/ (any white space).

Comment: "_Regarding the answer that is using split. ...  split on /\s+/_"  -- no, that is precisely what should not be done.  I suggest reading through `split` documentation, as stated in that answer, to learn what `' '` does and what `/\s+/` does.